# Почему Stable diffusion ""nmkd"" Не видит .safetensors формат?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Я скачал попробовать [Stable diffusion nmkd](https://nmkd.itch.io/t2i-gui)
И скачал модель из сайта civitai.com
И она формата .safetensors но программа его не видит.
Я проверял ckpt он видит.
я читал [гитхаб](https://github.com/n00mkrad/text2image-gui)
И там сказано

> Convert Models: Allows you to convert model weights between Pytorch
> (ckpt/pt), Diffusers, Diffusers ONNX, and SafeTensors formats.

Может кото ни будь сказать может я делаю что ни будь не так или я неправильно что то понял.
версия 1 9 1

Comment: Там есть конвертер (правда он сломан). Можно использовать сторонние конвертеры, но лучше просто взять другой софт

Comment: @vitidev Я почему то думал что он это делает автоматически. Не знаете какой конвертер лучше подойдет?

Comment: Ну вот [этот](https://github.com/diStyApps/Safe-and-Stable-Ckpt2Safetensors-Conversion-Tool-GUI) сконвертит за секунды. Но проще перейти на вебгуи, где хотя бы нет лимита размера промпта (помимо всего другого)